# drawBorder function not working in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've added the following to the top of the Gd2.php in Magento to create a red border around catalog images but I'm getting no border. Am I missing something?

```
/*
* Function to create a border around an image
*/
function drawBorder($image_name, $r = 255, $g = 0, $b = 0, $thickness = 30)
{
$image = ImageCreateFromJPEG($image_name);
$color = ImageColorAllocate($img, $r, $g, $b);

$x1 = 0;
$y1 = 0;
$x2 = ImageSX($image) - 1;
$y2 = ImageSY($image) - 1;

for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++)
{
ImageRectangle($image, $x1++, $y1++, $x2--, $y2--, $color);
}

return $image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS. Add below class in your styles.css file

```
.ImageBorder
{
    border: 3px solid;
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

In your list.phtml, do it like below with your `<img>` tag

```
<img class="ImageBorder" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(true); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

Comment: Where would I add your second part within Magento? to the same file or within list.phtml?

Comment: If you just want a border around your catalog product images, you can do it via css too.

Comment: I'm not able to use css to add border as the image has keepFrame (true) which calculates the empty areas of the image dimensions and makes them to a square. Which is why I need to add the border with php BEFORE the keepFrame calculations are made.

Comment: Also, adding keepFrame(false) won't work as it then breaks the responsive resizing and the alignment of the images in a row.

Comment: Did you tried `backgroundColor(array(255, 255, 255));` which Magento provides ?

Comment: Yes, this just changes the whole of the background color that uses the keepFrame calculation.

Comment: Even if you use `keepFrame(true);` and apply CSS it will work. The "keepFrame" parameter guarantees that the image will be not cropped. When "keepAspectRatio" is false the "keepFrame" will not work.

Comment: with keepFrame(true) the css border is added to the outside of this calculated extra value. Means, the image sits in the middle of a square and the css border outlines the outside of the square. I want the border to outline the inside image.

Comment: I need to look at your image for more details

Comment: Do not apply backgroundColor();

Comment: The border remains on the outside of the calculated block not immediately around the image.

Comment: I've tried many different variations but my question still comes back to the original - why won't function drawBorder work within Gd2.php?

Comment: To make your GD function work, you need to ensure that PHP code is the only thing on the page. No HTML, no spaces before or after the PHP code, etc, the only thing it should send to the browser should be the image data.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1usqhbzklkbk2f/Gd2.php - my full gd2.php around line 307 is where I've added new function

Comment: How are you outputting the image in your phtml file ?

Comment: <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(false)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepTransparency(false)->keepFrame(true)->resize(350,350) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>